# Is there any way to get the ID of a Process Builder to apex class?

Tags: apex, process-builder, metadata, xml

I want to get the ID's of all the Process Builder (that I created) into an Apex Class.

Is there any way to do this by means of Metadata API (or) Is there any API directly to retrieve them?